# Chess board and piece design in java

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on to do my assignment. It is a chess design(AI, GUI not required), I have piece class. The piece class has two variables: color and name. So far I have a "move method" like this in this class.
     `

```
  public void move(Piece piece,int x,int y)
  {
 int a=0;
 int b=0;

  for(int i=0;i<Board.grid.length;i++) {
   for(int r=0;r<Board.grid[i].length;r++) {
   if(Board.grid[i][r]==piece)
   a=i;
   b=r;
   if(Board.getisnull(x, y)){
   Board.grid[a][b]=null;
   Board.grid[x][y]=piece;
   }
  }
 }
Board.grid[u][t]=null;
}
`
```

In this code, I want to find an index which is the old index of the piece I want to move, then moving it then setting its old index to null but this is not working. I can see the name on screen but not the color. Also, old index is not set to null. How to do it? I started to think using an object(piece) array but how?

Comment: sorry..there is no u and t.they are a and b..i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small hint:

> //finds the piece equal to name and color of our piece.so 
>   if(Board.grid[i][y].equals(name) || Piece.color.equals(color))

This doesn't fit together, since the check is "equal to name OR equal color". I think you want to change it to: `if(Board.grid[i][y].equals(name) && Piece.color.equals(color))`

> Piece.setColor(color);//set this piece's color

Huh? What are you doing that for? Shouln't `Piece` keep its color all the time?

> if(Board.getisnull(x, y)==true)

You're redefining y in your loop so y is not the parameter you passed in to the method.

Basically, I'd redefine the method (to keep is as close to the OP as possible, note that OOP wise there could be even better design, subclassing Piece etc.):

```
//Board.grid[][] should be a 'Piece[8][8]';


//edit: rename parameters for clarity
public void move( Piece piece,int targetX,int targetY) 
{
  if( Board.getisnull(targetX, targetY) )//method in other class checks the indexes if null
  {
    //remove the piece from the field/index
    Board.grid[piece.x][piece.y]=null;

    //add the piece to the target field and update its position
    piece.x = targetX;
    piece.y = targetY;
    Board.grid[targetX][targetY]=piece;

  }
  else
  {
    //handle that case, e.g. by throwing an exeption
  }
}
```

Now you'd get the piece you want to move (which knows its index), calculate the target position and call `move(piece, targetX, targetY);`

Comment: but with this code,piece's old index(the place before move) is not set to null..?the x,y is the wanted indexes to be moved.

Comment: This line sets the old index to null: `Board.grid[piece.x][piece.y]=null;` Note that piece.x and piece.y are the piece's current index which changes afterwards.

Comment: so you saying first delete the piece,then add a new piece same with deleted one,to x,y location..

Comment: No you don't delete the piece you just delete one reference to the piece and add another one. Also consider Zombies answer in order to improve your design, but for a start you should be fine doing the above.

Comment: sorry if i interrupt you permenantly.:)but i dont understand why you did this."Board.grid[piece.x][piece.y]=null;".how it knows its old position..at piece.x and piece.y,where the x and y come from..

Comment: x and y would be members of the class `Piece` and you'd set those values when initializing the board and when moving the piece.